# How can I properly manage multiple sockets opening and closing a lot?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets

I know how to open a `socket` in `objective-c` and how to send and receive `data`. I have always made a `socket` handler `object`, with a simple open method and a `callback` method. Something like this:

```
+ (void)openWithUrl:(NSString *)url {
    @try {
        CFReadStreamRef readStream;
        CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
        CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (__bridge CFStringRef)url, 9443, &readStream, &writeStream);
        CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);
        CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);

        inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;
        outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;

        NSMutableDictionary *sslSettings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [sslSettings setObject:NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLLevel];
        [sslSettings setObject:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLAllowsAnyRoot];
        [sslSettings setObject:url forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamSSLPeerName];
        [inputStream setProperty:sslSettings forKey:(NSString *)kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings];
    }
    @catch (NSException *e) {
        NSLog(@"exception: %@",e);
    }

    @try {
        [inputStream setDelegate:static_self];
        [inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [inputStream open];

        [outputStream setDelegate:static_self];
        [outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
        [outputStream open];
    }
    @catch (NSException *e) {
        NSLog(@"exception: %@",e);
    }
}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        NSError *theError = [theStream streamError];

        if (theError == NULL) {
            switch (streamEvent) {
                case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted: {
                    break;
                }

                case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable: {
                    //handle incoming data here
                    break;
                }

                case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable: {
                    //send some data here
                    break;
                }

                case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred: {
                    break;
                }

                case NSStreamEventEndEncountered: {
                    break;
                }

                default: {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Pretty simple. Now, for a `voip app` I'm making, I'm using a `signaling` `server` that requires me to connect using two `sockets`.

- One `control socket` to send data. This `socket` needs to be opened,
  sent some `data`, then close again. After receiving the response from
  the server, I close the `socket` and open the next one.
- One `waiting socket` to receive `data`. This one is opened after the
  `control socket` is done. I open this `socket` and send a wait
  `signal` to the server, whenever the server has something to tell
  me(someone is calling, someone connected/disconnected etc...), he
  sends `data` on this `waiting socket`. If I need to open the `control
  socket` again to send some data myself, I close the `waiting socket`
  and it gets opened after the `control socket` is done.

I tried using my old way, I copy'pasted it from SO long ago, and it has always been good enough. However, I feel it's getting harder to manage what is going on with the `sockets`. Because they open and close all the time I miss packets sometimes. I also can't send a lot of messages in a short time span, because then the `socket` closes (reopens) before it is done sending the `data`.

How can I deal with this? Is there a `design pattern` that allows me to use two `sockets` like I described above? I'd rather not use `third party libraries` unless there is no other way.

Comment: Please don't use code formatting for things that aren't code.  It makes your question incredibly painful/difficult to read.  Also, it's not clear from your question why you need to close the sockets?

Comment: @sapi I'm not sure where you see code formatting for non-code, because I don't see it... I also explained why I need to close the socket, because the server protocol requires it.